# PHP syntax error depends on version / environment

Tags: nginx, php

I have two servers.
On the first (local) code works properly,
on the second one (stage) I get syntax error - ofcourse checked a script file (scp & diff).
Braces are enclosed correctly.

Command used to check

```
php -l template.phtml
```

**stage** error

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in template.phtml on line 135
Errors parsing template.phtml
```

135 line of file

```
    <?php $i++; } ?>
```

**local** output for lint (tried also with second local server)

```
No syntax errors detected in template.phtml
```

**stage** version

```
PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.5 (cli) (built: Jun 25 2014 17:14:14)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

**local** version

```
PHP 5.4.24 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2014 21:32:15)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

**antoher local server** version

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.14 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep  4 2014 07:08:49)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

In the stage is installed php-fpm (I'm not deal with it).

Any ideas?
Should I deal with php.ini or just reinstall php?

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible to remove that line (and all code from whatever opens the `{`) and your code still do something, and if so is there a different PHP error? Can you show the full code for template.phtml? Do you use short tags in any of your code?

Comment: Thinking about it, it's probably something which has changed in PHP v 5.5

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're mixing PHP and HTML.  Try the [colon syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for that.

Although the best practice would be to separate the PHP code from the HTML code.  Something like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) can help with that.

Comment: Why would that explain it works on one server and not another? Also, separating PHP and HTML doesn't mean *not using PHP at all* within views/templates/etc. Otherwise how do you get data from your engine/framework to display within your HTML?

Comment: The fact that they're different servers is not important, it's that they're different versions of PHP.

Comment: Your answer doesn't cover what you said in your comment though, and your answer doesn't answer the question, really.Mixing PHP and HTML is fine, they open and close the PHP tags in their example code, so I doubt that's their actual issue. Especially given it works on another server.

Comment: My assumption was that something had changed between the versions which affects how it deals with PHP blocks.

Comment: You've only shown one line of code, and that has a mismatched brace in a PHP block.  Either the error message on stage is correct or there's more code split between other PHP blocks.  If there are more PHP blocks then the problem may be how they're all combined by the PHP interpreter.